# How do you embed a video in an MVC application?

Tags: azure, asp.net-mvc-4, html5-video, azure-web-app-service

I want to embed a demo video of my product on my MVC web site.  I've read through other posts on this forum and appears the best approach is this:

```
            <video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
                <source src="~/Files/Demo Video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
                Your browser does not support the video tag.
            </video>
```

Oddly, this works when I run it locally, but when I publish it to my Azure web site, I get the video player to show, but it gives me message:

```
             Invalid Source
```

Is there some trick to publishing video content in a 'Files' directory that I'm missing?  In Visual Studio, the 'Demo Video.mp4' has the 'Build Action' as 'Content' and the 'Copy to Output Directory' set to 'Copy if Newer'.  What am I missing?

Comment: this link help you...https://www.scottlilly.com/how-to-use-azure-as-a-cdn-for-an-embedded-video-in-an-mvc-website/

Comment: How do you reference a file in storage?  I'm able to reference a file in the wwwroot directory tree that is created for my Web App, but I'm not sure how an HTML page can reference a Blob in the Azure storage.

Answer (score 2):

Please try to add MIME type for .MP4 file in your Web.config via App Service Editor.

```
<system.webServer>
  <staticContent>
    <mimeMap fileExtension=".mp4" mimeType="video/mp4" />
  </staticContent>
</system.webServer>
```

Besides, please make sure if the `Demo Video.mp4` is in `Files` folder on your Azure website. And I recommend that you could store your videos (or other static files) in [Azure storage](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/storage-introduction).

**Edit**:

The following are my Project Folder Structure and main code that I used to display video in web page. If possible, you could try to create a new MVC project and do same thing as I did, and then publish the project to a new Azure website to check if it will works fine.

***Project Folder Structure***

[image]

***Put the below code in your `About` page***

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "About";
}
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<h3>@ViewBag.Message</h3>

@*<p>Use this area to provide additional information.</p>*@

<video controls="controls" autoplay="autoplay">
    <source src="~/Files/Demo Video.mp4" type="video/mp4" />
    Your browser does not support the video tag.
</video>
```

***Browse the website***

[image]

Comment: I verified that the Demo Video.mp4 was in the Files folder on the website.  I added the <staticContent> section to the Web.config.  No change.  I'm still getting the 'Invalid Source' message.  This is strange because it works locally.

Comment: Oddly, if I go to the site using FTP and select the 'Demo Video.mp4', it plays just fine.  So it runs locally, and it runs from Chrome using FTP connected to the uploaded website data.

Comment: I edited my reply, if you create a new MVC project and do same thing as I did, does it works fine?

Comment: The 'mime' settings appear to be unnecessary, but yes, but it did start working when I created a new MVC project.  Odd.  The old MVC (about two years back) didn't want to find the content when published.  Thanks for the suggestion.